# Updating data in Next JS page based on change in MongoDB database without refreshing the page

Tags: mongodb, next.js, crud

I am basically interacting with a MongoDB database from my NextJS site and displaying data from it. I am implementing CRUD functionality so that new content can be added and existing content can be deleted from the site. However, the updates only show up after refreshing the page. I want it to show up immediately as it is done.

I'm omitting useless code, but basically here is the relevant code from one of the pages.

First I am getting data from the database using `getStaticProps`:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  try {
    const client = await clientPromise;
    const db = await client.db("AdminCredentials");
    const siteAdmins = await db.collection("credentials").find({}).toArray();
    return {
      props: {
        siteAdmins: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(siteAdmins)),
      },
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    throw new Error(e);
  }
}
```

and then I am rendering it like this. I'm using Chakra UI.

```
const Admins = ({ siteAdmins }) => {
  
  const removeAdmin = async (userName) => {
    const res = await fetch("/api/removeAdmin", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ userName: userName }),
    }).then((data) => {
      return data.json();
    });
    console.log(res);
    const revalidate = await fetch("/api/revalidate").then((data) => {
      return data.json();
    });
    console.log(revalidate);
  };
  return (
        <div>
          <SimpleSidebar>
            <TableContainer>
              <Table variant="simple">
                <Thead>
                  <Tr>
                    <Th>Username</Th>
                    <Th>Level of access</Th>
                    <Th>Action</Th>
                  </Tr>
                </Thead>
                <Tbody>
                  {siteAdmins.map((admin, id) => (
                    <Tr key={id}>
                      <Td>{admin.userName}</Td>
                      <Td>{admin.accountType}</Td>
                      
                        <Td>
                          <Button
                            mx="2px"
                            bg="red.500"
                            _hover={{ bg: "red.600" }}
                            onClick={() => removeAdmin(admin.userName)}
                          >
                            Remove
                          </Button>
                        </Td>
                      
                    </Tr>
                  ))}
                </Tbody>
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>
          </SimpleSidebar>
        </div>   
  );
};
```

Here is the code in "/api/revalidate"

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    await res.revalidate("/admins");
    return res.json({ revalidated: true });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ revalidated: false });
  }
}
```

As far as my understanding goes, I assumed calling the `revalidate` endpoint would automatically update the content on the site the moment it is updated in MongoDB, following this documentation https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#using-on-demand-revalidation, but that is not happening and you have to manually refresh the site to see the change. I want the change to reflect on the site as soon as the 'Remove' button is pressed. How do I do it?

Comment: You should take a look at. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/changeStream/

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is that you are using `getStaticProps` instead of `getInitialProps` or `getServerSideProps`. Then change revalidation rules according to your needs.

Using getStaticProps, next.js will generate a static page during build.